# Save file object into a file - sweetalert2 - javascript - php

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2

I set up a SweetAlert2 popup with a file input (only images are allowed), according to [example](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-types):

```
const {value: file} = await swal({
                title: "Image upload",
                text: "Upload your profile image",
                input: 'file',
                inputAttributes: {
                    'accept': 'image/*',
                    'aria-label': "Upload here your image"
                }
            });
```

and then I sent an ajax request through XMLHTTPRequest to a PHP file:

```
if (file) {
                if (!file) throw null;
                swal.showLoading();

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for modern browsers
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for old IE browsers
                    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    // success message
                };

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "includes/uploadimage.php?image=" + file, true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            }
```

The PHP file would save the file object generated by SweetAlert2 input (and then passed through XMLHttpRequest) in a file on the server, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved out this by using a JS reader, the reading the data URI from it and sending it through FormData with a POST XMLHttpRequest.

```
if (file) {
                if (!file) throw null;
                swal.showLoading();
                const reader = new FileReader;
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    const fd = new FormData;
                    fd.append('image', e.target.result);
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for modern browsers
                        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for old IE browsers
                        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        // ... do something ...
                    };

                    xmlhttp.open("POST", "includes/uploadimage.php", true);
                    xmlhttp.send(fd);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        }
```